# User deleted but still showing in database and in view, How to delete it?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using .net MVC application where I have a list of users. I am deleting a specific user from Admin panel but is still showing in database and in view.

How to delete it?

Code:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    Domain.Entities.User dbuser = new Domain.Entities.User();
    bool isDone = _userService.Remove(id);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { msg = "record deleted successfully." });
}
```

Success message showing its deleted, but actually not because its still in database(Marked as deleted) and in view.

Comment: Are you calling SaveChanges() in the Remove() method?

Comment: share the implementation of `Remove()` method

Comment: You are creating a context, never using it, and then calling some service method. I suspect that the `Remove` method is where the problem is.